# Como mantener la búsqueda al cambiar de ruta en angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Buen día a todos,

Mi consulta es la siguiente:
Estoy realizando una búsqueda de datos consumiendo un servicio, los datos los muestro en una tabla y cada registro tiene asignado una ruta donde al hacer clic consumo otro servicio diferente para ver los detalles de ese registro, el cual me lleva a una nueva pagina donde muestro los datos del detalle, el problema es que quiero mantener la búsqueda anterior al regresar. Como puedo lograr esto, espero se pueda entender.

Comment: Puedes guardarlo en el localstorage o en un servicio que sea singleton

Comment: puede ser una solucion, Gracias por el dato.